# My APP got Suspended due to Violation of Spam policy

Tags: android, google-play

I'm really disappointed about this action my app was running on google play for more than 4 months and yesterday I made some updates by adding OfferToro and other networks.

Before this(more than a month), Google informed me that they stopped serving ads for my app.

My APP is about earning points by watching ads and downloading apps then the user can redeem it to real money.

I don't send any notification or email to the user. The only notification is when the offer completed or redeem request was sent by email.

ORIGINAL E-MAIL:

> Hi Developers at X,   After a recent review, YY has been removed from Google Play.
>   Publishing Status
>   Publishing status: Suspended
>   Your app has been suspended and removed due to a policy violation.
>   Reasons of violation
>   Issue: Violation of Spam policy
>   We don’t allow apps that spam users or Google Play, such as apps that send users unsolicited messages or apps that are duplicative and low-quality.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly be the 2nd part of the definition.

> ...or apps that are duplicative and low-quality.

If your app is just showing ads to the user, perhaps it doesn't offer enough and is deemed as just low-quality.